# trace keyboard inputs

Tags: c#

I hope to create application in c# to trace the keyboard raw inputs and replace that inputs
ex: if keydown > crtl+A  then  output> B
or input AB then out put > C

this is for support to local language typing.

Answer (score 2):

You should search that "Keyboard Hooks" on Google.

You should look at for Example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook